# I am unable to find out the memcheck error when i using valgrind on the given code

Tags: memory-leaks, memcheck

I am unable to detect the memory error(memcheck error) . when i run the code i see some unexpected output came. so please describe what is happening in thes code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getString()
{
    char message[100]="Hello World";
    char *ret = message;
    return ret;
}
void test4()
{
    printf("String: %s",getString());
}
int main()
{
    
    test4();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable **message** is local to the function **getString** and is on the stack.  After **getString** returns, **message** no longer exists, meaning that the pointer returned by **getString**, which was set to point to **message** is no longer valid.